# How to access the variable value outside loop in C++

Tags: c++, variables, while-loop, scope

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sqdnumber;
    int sqdNumber_result=0;
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin>>sqdnumber;
    cout<<"\n";

    while(sqdnumber==0)
    {
        int remainder=sqdnumber%10;
        sqdNumber_result=(remainder*remainder)+sqdNumber_result;
        sqdnumber=sqdnumber/10;
    }

    cout<<sqdNumber_result;
}
```

I am trying to print sum of square of individual digit but the variable sqdNumber_result is not accessible outside loop. Could you tell me how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `sqdNumber_result` is perfectly accessible outside of the loop. Either this is the wrong code, or you misinterpreted the compiler error message (if any).

Comment: It looks like your code will just get stuck in an infinite loop after a quick look through.

Comment: Most probably, your problem is that you inverted the `while` condition - you want `while(sqdnumber!=0)`.

Comment: Remember, it's a `while` loop, not an `until` loop. C has no until

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqdNumber_result` is perfectly accessible outside of the loop, and [your code compiles fine](https://ideone.com/DUDUnr).

I suspect that you got strange ideas about variable shadowing because your code outputs 0 for any (nonzero) input; that's because you got the `while` condition wrong: `while(sqdnumber==0)` won't make you even enter the loop whatever input you provide, and will get you stuck forever in the loop for zero input.

You want `while(sqdnumber!=0)`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I did mistake. But is it possible to access variable value outside for loop and do-while loop as well?

Comment: @MArjun Why wouldn't it be possible? That's where the variable is declared.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, Yeah from the solution to above problem, it seems that it is possible. I am new to C++, so may be it sounds silly question.